# Where do I put my c wire the un used or c wire for me is blue but where do I connect it to?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I’m not really sure where to tie this blue wire into for my thermostat (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJoRS.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the rest of the furnace's wiring compartment please, as well as of the wiring diagram posted at the furnace?

Comment: There ya go thank you for your help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Include it in the nut with the red and grey wires in it

Given that the wiring diagram for your furnace says that the grey wire going into the thermostat wiring compartment is your C wire, we can connect the blue wire to the thermostat into the existing junction there to make it a C wire for your thermostat's use.  This is further substantiated by the fact the yellow wire in your thermostat cable goes off into the white wire in the compressor cable, which leaves the red wire in the compressor cable to return 24V control power back to the transformer, which implies that the red wire must be connected to the furnace's C wire.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I did that tho my thermostat still didn’t turn on. Would I need a bigger nut for the wires the orange one is small and I don’t think they fit in it all together?

Comment: @isaacnewton -- you may need to go to the next larger size wirenut, yes

Comment: I finally got the thermostat on but when I set the thermostat to a higher temp where my blower fan is it starts to glow red or orange color like something’s hot is that normal? I’m sorry for being so annoying with the questions but I don’t want to burn down the house.

Comment: @isaacnewton -- if the *blower* is glowing, I'd turn the furnace off and have it looked at.